# Angular ag-grid how to conditionally render header

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular11

I am new to ag-grid with Angular. I have simple html table to list users. And i want to use ag-grid for this. There are few columns which shouldn't be displayed if there is no permission. I am not sure how to achieve this using ag-grid. Can anyone please help me how to achieve this?

Existing html table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30">&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <ng-container *requireAnyPermission="[SensitiveAccessPermission]">
        <th>Modified by</th>
        <th>Modified date</th>
      </ng-container>
      <th *requireAnyPermission="[SensitiveAccessPermission]">Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let person of people">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-label="Name">{{ person.name }}</td>
        <ng-container *requireAnyPermission="[SensitiveAccessPermission]">
          <td data-label="Modified by">{{ person.modifiedBy }}</td>
          <td data-label="Modified date">
           {{ person.modified | dateTimeFormat }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <td *requireAnyPermission="[SensitiveAccessPermission]" data-label="Active">
          <ng-container *ngIf="person.isActive; then checkTemplate"></ng-container>
        </td>       
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have the ag-grid column definition as below:

```
const COLUMNS: ColDef[] = [
  { headerName: '', field: '' },
  { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', filter: true },
  { headerName: 'Modified by', field: 'modifiedBy', filter: true },
  { headerName: 'Modified date', field: 'modified', filter: true },
  { headerName: 'Active', field: 'isActive', filter: true },
];
```

How to achieve the same with ag-grid.

*requireAnyPermission is custom directive

```
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
  selector: '[requireAnyPermission]'
})
export class RequireAnyPermissionDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private _onDestroy = new Subject();
  private _reverse = false;
  private _anyPermissions: Array<string | PermissionCodeWithMask>;

  @Input() set requireAnyPermission(
    permissions: Array<string | PermissionCodeWithMask>
  ) {
    this._anyPermissions = permissions;
    this.updateView();
  }

  @Input() set requireAnyPermissionReverse(reverse: boolean) {
    this._reverse = reverse;
    this.updateView();
  }

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<HTMLElement>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._onDestroy.next();
  }

  private updateView() {
    if (this._anyPermissions) {
      this.userService
        .userHasAnyPermissions(this._anyPermissions)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
        .subscribe((hasPermission) => {
          this.viewContainerRef.clear();
          if (
            (hasPermission && !this._reverse) ||
            (!hasPermission && this._reverse)
          ) {
            this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
          }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by either constructing the column definitions array programmatically based on the permissions the user have OR remove the columns you want to hide from `COLUMNS` on component initialization

In both cases you would have to call

`gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);`

after you are done

Look at updating column defs example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-updating-definitions/#example-update-column-definition)
You wanna do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can show/hide columns:-

```
 this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible([...visibleCols], true);  // show columns
 this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible([...hiddenCols], false);  // hide columns
```

**If you want those column, not available in the grid:-**

> when creating `columnDefs` for grid, dont add in `columnDefs` conditionally

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is simple method (* For Big Project and multiple change)

First get all column list for grid like.

```
 getKeys(obj: []) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
  }
```

this getKeys method give you all ColumnName of over array

```
    //item is json response from over server.
var columns = this.getKeys(item[0]);
var colObj = {};
var gridcolumnDefs = [];

for (var i = 0; i & lt; columns.length; i++) {
  var visible = true;

  switch (columns[i].toLocaleLowerCase()) {

    case 'columnname1':
      colObj = {
        field: columns[i],
        sortable: false
      }
      break;
    case 'columnname2':
      visible = false;
      colObj = {
        field: columns[i],
        sortable: false
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;

  }

  if (visible) {
    if (colObj != undefined)
      this.gridcolumnDefs.push(colObj);
  }
}
```

// set column grid
this.GridName.setColumnDefs(this.gridcolumnDefs)

please try and check.